# Is it possible to make an order via phone or using IVR in magento?

Tags: magento, ivr

Is it possible to make an order via phone or using IVR in magento?

Answer (score 0):

In a very general, hand-wavey sense, sure it is. At the end of the day, Magento is driven by a database and can be manipulated as such. (Hey, it's just code, right?)

Are you asking about any particular IVR, or planning to code one from scratch? Is there some issue in particular that concerns you about creating such a system for Magento? With a little more detail, I think we'll be able to help you much more.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe